# How to scale and add correct a logo in ffmpeg command?

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, scale, scaling, watermark

I am trying to apply a watermark and also to scale it to the current video size via ffmpeg command:

Here is my inital comand that works without watermark

```
ffmpeg -v 0 -vcodec h264_qsv -i 'udp://@some.ip:1234?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1&buffer_size=1000000' -vf scale=iw:ih -profile baseline -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -deinterlace -vcodec h264_qsv -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 3500k -preset veryfast -vb 2000k -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/app/720
```

Now I tried to add the picture as a watermark. There was a conflict while using with `-vf scale=-1:ih*.5`, in order to eliminate the problem I used `-s 1280x720` to specify the resolution for the video stream, it worked but not properly.

```
ffmpeg -v 0 -vcodec h264_qsv -i 'udp://@some.ip:1234?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1&buffer_size=1000000' -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -s 1280x720 -profile baseline -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -deinterlace -vcodec h264_qsv -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 3500k -preset veryfast -vb 2000k -f flv rtmp://some.ip/app/720
```

**The problem:**

How can I specify in the ffmpeg command the both sizes of video and logo(watermark) so they don't conflict with each other and they auto adjust like  `-vf scale=-1:ih*.5` dose.

Thank you!

Comment: See [here](http://superuser.com/a/1053647/114058).

Comment: @Mulvya Thanks, I saw that post but for me is very confusing all this ffmpeg commands. In your answer on that link I am confusing with ` -map [v] -map 0:a -y -b:v  `. Can you please explain your command or edit mine? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The scale2ref filter allows one to a video/image stream with reference to the dimensions of another video or image stream

e.g.

```
ffmpeg -v 0 -vcodec h264_qsv -i 'udp://@some.ip:1234?fifo_size=1000000&overrun_nonfatal=1&buffer_size=1000000' \
-loop 1 -i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw/8:-1[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=10:10[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a \
-profile baseline -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64k \
-deinterlace -vcodec h264_qsv -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 3500k \
-preset veryfast -vb 2000k \
-f flv rtmp://some.ip/app/720
```

Here `1:v` - the logo image - is being scaled to 1/8th the width of `[0:v]`, the H.264 stream.

---

For the command given in the comments:

```
ffmpeg -v 0 -vcodec h264_qsv -i 'input' \
-loop 1 -i logo.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw:ih[v0]; \
                [1:v][v0]scale2ref=iw/8:-1[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=10:10[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 0:a \
-profile baseline -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64k \
-deinterlace -vcodec h264_qsv -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 3500k \
-preset veryfast -vb 2000k \
-f flv out1 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:ih/2[v0]; \
                [1:v][v0]scale2ref=iw/8:-1[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=10:10[v2]" \
-map "[v2]" -map 0:a \
-profile baseline -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64k \
-deinterlace -vcodec h264_qsv -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 2000k \
-preset veryfast -vb 1000k \
-f flv out2 \
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=-1:ih/4[v0]; \
                [1:v][v0]scale2ref=iw/8:-1[logo][0v];[0v][logo]overlay=10:10[v3]" \
-map "[v3]" -map 0:a \
-profile baseline -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64k \
-deinterlace -vcodec h264_qsv -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 1000k \
-preset veryfast -vb 512k \
-f flv out3 \
```

Comment: Your command works fine, thank you. But I have a problem. I am streaming using 1 ffmpeg command 3 rtmp streams (1 input- 3 different quality outputs).   How can I adjust for this command that is almost the same mentioned above to use logo?

Comment: ffmpeg -v 0 -vcodec h264_qsv -i 'input' -vf scale=iw:ih -profile baseline -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -deinterlace -vcodec h264_qsv -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 3500k -preset veryfast -vb 2000k -f flv out1 -vf scale=-1:ih*.5 -profile baseline -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -deinterlace -vcodec h264_qsv -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 2000k  -preset veryfast -vb 1000k -f flv out2 -vf scale=-1:ih*.25 -profile baseline -acodec aac -ac 1 -ar 44100 -ab 64k -deinterlace -vcodec h264_qsv -bufsize 4000k -maxrate 1000k -preset veryfast -vb 512k -f flv out3

Comment: Thank you! I owe you minimum a beer!