# ffmpeg scale logo size according to video size

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

I have a ffmpeg command which is working fine to inject 2 image on the top left and bottom right of the video.

```
ffmpeg -i ori.mp4 -y -i 1.png -i 2.png -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]overlay=20:20[bkg]; \
[bkg][2:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-20:(main_h-overlay_h)-20" \
-codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a aac -strict -2 out1.mp4
```

this command working fine with video that has large size like 720x480, however when the input video size is 320x240 size, it will overlay half of the video size.

1.png size is: 160x100

2.png size is: 341x44

any idea how to combine the **scale2ref** into above command?

been trying solution from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200506/how-to-scale-and-add-correct-a-logo-in-ffmpeg-command) so far no luck.

**update 1:** i found this command from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/809820/scale-watermark-overlay-by-video-size-with-ffmpeg/1053634)

```
ffmpeg -i ori.mp4 -y -i 1.png \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw*0.25:-1[logo1][base]; \
[base][logo1]overlay=20:20[v]" -map [v] -map 0:a \
-codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a aac -strict -2 out2.mp4
```

that command work fine to get one image to scale.

**update 2:**

```
ffmpeg -i ori.mp4 -y -i 1.png -i 2.png \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw*0.25:-1[logo1][base];\
[base][logo1]overlay=20:20[v];[2:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw*0.30:-1[logo2][base2];\
[base2][logo2]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)-20:(main_h-overlay_h)-20[v]" \
-map [v] -map 0:a -codec:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a aac -strict -2 out4.mp4
```

tried above, nothing work. got error like this

```
Filter overlay has an unconnected output
```

any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i ori.mp4 -y -i 1.png -i 2.png -filter_complex \
"[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=160/100*oh:ih/5[v1][bk1];[bk1][v1]overlay=20:20[bkg]; \
 [2:v][bkg]scale2ref=341/44*oh:ih/11[v2][bk2];[bk2][v2]overlay=W-w-20:H-h-20" \
-c:v libx264 -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p \
-c:a aac -strict -2 out1.mp4
```